# /binarysearch.java:2: error: <identifier> expected

Tags: java

```
public class binarysearch {
    public static int search(num, target_value) {
        int low = 0;
        int mid;
        int high = num.length - 1;
        
        while (low < high) {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;

            if (num[mid] == target_value) {
                return mid;
            }

            if (num[mid] < target_value){
                low = mid + 1;
            } else {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        binarysearch ob = new binarysearch();
        int target_value = 69;
        int[] num = {10,23,45,11,69,81};
        int result = ob.search(num,target_value);
        
        if (result == -1) {
          System.out.println("Element not present");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Element is present" + mid);
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me what exactly I am doing wrong here. I am facing a compilation error while executing my code.

I was trying to implement Binary Search and I am receiving this error :

```
/binarysearch.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
    public static int search(num,target_value)
                                ^
/binarysearch.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
    public static int search(num,target_value)
                                             ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Java is already telling you what the issue is, you need to add the type of the parameters in the method signature.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out as I am new to Java language.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bahij.Mik mentioned in the comments, you are missing the [types](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_data_types.asp) in the method signature. So change the `search` method to:

```
public static int search(int[] num, int target_value) {
  ..
}
```

*N.B. Check also this [Guide to the Static Keyword](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static) in Java!*

Answer (score 0):

You have to add type parameters in the method

```
public static int search(int[] num, int target_value)
```

and if you make the method static you dont have to declaration the object

you can call the method directly

```
int result = search(num,target_value);
```